# Issue with jsPDF and html2canvas: Saved PDF is Pixelated

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm working on a project where I've implemented a form in HTML, and I'm using `html2canvas` along with `jsPDF` to capture and save the form as a PDF. However, when I open the saved PDF, it appears to be pixelated.

I've tried adjusting the DPI using the `scale` option in `html2canvas` and configuring the `jsPDF` constructor options for better quality, but the issue persists. The saved PDF looks pixelated, and I'm looking for a solution to improve the resolution.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```html
<!-- Include libraries -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your form goes here -->
<form id="patientForm">
  <!-- Your form fields go here -->
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

  <!-- Add more fields as needed -->

  <button type="button" onclick="generatePDF()">Save as PDF</button>
</form>

<script>
  window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

  function generatePDF() {
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      unit: 'mm',
      format: 'a4',
      compress: true,
    });

    // Adjustments for A4 size paper
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    // HTML element to capture
    const formElement = document.getElementById("patientForm");

    // Increase the scale for better resolution
    const scale = 2;

    // Use html2canvas library to capture the form as an image
    html2canvas(formElement, { scale: scale })
      .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        // Add image to PDF with higher resolution
        pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, undefined, 'FAST');

        // Save the PDF
        pdf.save("patient_form.pdf");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
      });
  }
</script>
```